# Data of jQuery array won't show up on a database after transferring its data to a PHP array in another file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I am sending values of a jQuery array to another PHP array *from {file.js} to {file.php}* but the transferred data won't show up on the database **An empty row in the targeted column will show up in the the table of the DataBase while the ID will occur**

The script that I wrote on file.js is the following :

```
var emailText;
var emailArray = new Array();
$("#emailAddress").keypress(function (event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        var emailText = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        emailArray.push(emailText);
        $('ul').prepend('<li>' + emailText + '<span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>');
        $.post(
            "http://localhost/main_dir/dir/file.php", 
            emailArray,
            function(){
            alert('Your email has been added to the database successfully');
           }
        );
    }
});
```

And the code that I wrote on file.php is the following :

```
<?php

require_once 'dbhandler.php';

$add_email = array("");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $add_email = $_POST['emailArray'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO databse (new_added_email) VALUES ('$add_email');";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}


?>
```

Comment: `...../file.php", {emailArray : emailArray},function....`

Comment: When I applied what you suggested, it outputted in the console (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':')

Comment: Maybe because I posted my comment with `(` instead of `{` .. anyways your data should be like `{  data1 : data1value , data2 : data2value }`

Comment: Thank you Youssef, this time it showed in the table word **array**. How I can now insert the data of the array into the table

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection.. If you put this online, your db is unprotected.

Comment: @Wimanicesir, I didn't know that I will see what I can do about that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st:** I don't know what is the purpose of using `array` for emails while *ID must be unique* and you must have only one email input *So no need for array in your case*

**2nd:** As I posted on the comment data should post between curly braces `{}`

**3rd:** Search for any kind of validation to validate the data posted to the database

**4th:** It will be better if you post the email to the php/database then when returned prepend the email to the user

**In js**

```
$("#emailAddress").keypress(function (event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        var $this = $(this);
        var emailText = $this.val();
        if(validateEmail(emailText)){
         $.post(
            "http://localhost/main_dir/dir/file.php", 
            {email : email},
            function(data){
              console.log(data);
              $this.val("");
              $('ul').prepend('<li>' + data + '<span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>');
              alert('Your email has been added to the database successfully');
           }
        );
       }else{
          alert(emailText+' Not valid email');
       }
    }
});

function validateEmail(email) {
     const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
     return re.test(email);
}
```

**In php**

```
<?php

require_once 'dbhandler.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $add_email = $_POST['email'];
    // check for email validation 
    // if(email_is_valid){
      $sql = "INSERT INTO databse (new_added_email) VALUES ('$add_email');";
    
      if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
         echo $add_email;
      }
    // } 
}


?>
```

I added `function validateEmail(email)` in js to check email validation you'll need another one for php validation just search for it then use it in php file before dealing with the database

Comment: It worked after few modifications.. Thank you a lot Mohamed Yousef, you truly helped me

Comment: You'r totally welcome @LakrariYoussef .. Have a great day :-)